# Customize Commit message while using npm version patch

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-commit

Is it possible to customize the commit message while using `npm version patch`?

I' d like to change it to `:up-arrow: @VERSIONNUMBER`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since npm 2.7.4 (and [commit 3703b0b, March 2015](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/3703b0b87c127a64649bdbfc3bc697ebccc4aa24)):

> The message in `npm version -m <message>` is mapped to the `message` config parameter in `.npmrc`.

That does not seem to be tied specifically to `patch` only though.
[This test](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/e013d3156a465f86ac378b2f3898322a530a4f38) shows a config which modifies the commit message:

```
sign-git-tag=false
message=":bookmark: %s"
```

You can try and replace `:bookmark:` with `:up-arrow:`.